# Bootstrap tabs - Next & previous Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I am using Bootstrap 3.4.

I am using tab-pills on a form with 3 tabs.

I am trying to place next & previous buttons to aid navigation between the tab form.

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297964/bootstrap-tabs-next-previous-buttons-for-forms) on the topic (and the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/120472)), which is exactly what I require, and I applied the necessary code.

On my form, in all 3 tabs, I always see the next1 button, I never see the other buttons.

I finally figured out that the error is to do with the class=active on the `<li class="active">` line of code> (or at least I am almost certain this is the error).

I have searched Google and SO to figure out how to get the js code working, but I cannot figure out to correct this simple issue. I have exhausted all my attempts, so I turn to SO for assistance.

**Can anyone suggest how I might correct this?**

Here is my js code:

```
$('.btnNext').click(function(){
    $('.nav-pills > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
    $('.nav-pills > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" id="id_link_tab1" href="#tab1">
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o icon_size26"></i>
            &nbsp;Tab #1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a data-toggle="tab" id="id_link_tab2" href="#tab2">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text icon_size26"></i>
            &nbsp;Tab #2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a data-toggle="tab" id="id_link_tab3" href="#tab3">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o icon_size26"></i>   
            &nbsp;Tab #3
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next2</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created this jsfiddle using your code, and it seems to work just fine. Perhaps you have other javascript issues that are standing in your way.  Check the console output in your browser's developer tools for any javascript errors.  https://jsfiddle.net/wqmf8ad6/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!--Nav tabs-->
    <div class="tabs-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav classic-tabs tabs-3" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item nav-item-panel-1">
                <a class="nav-link waves-light active" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel-1" aria-controls="panel-1" role="tab">First Tab</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-item-panel-2">
                <a class="nav-link waves-light" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel-2" aria-controls="panel-2" role="tab">Second Tab</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-item-panel-3">
                <a class="nav-link waves-light" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel-3" aria-controls="panel-3" role="tab">Third Tab</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!--Tab panels-->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <!--Panel 1-->
        <div class="tab-pane fade in show active" id="panel-1" role="tabpanel">
            Test1
        </div>
        <!--Panel 2-->
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="panel-2" role="tabpanel">
            Test2
        </div>
        <!--Panel 3-->
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="panel-3" role="tabpanel">
            Test3
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn" id="prevtab" type="button" data-toggle="tab">Prev</button>
            <button class="btn" id="nexttab" type="button" data-toggle="tab">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>


  $(document).ready(function () {
        let tabs = $('.tabs-wrapper li');
        $('#prevtab').on('click', function () {
            console.log( tabs.find('.active').parent())
            tabs.find('.active').parent().prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
        });
        $('#nexttab').on('click', function () {
            tabs.find('.active').parent().next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
        });
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since it consists only of code, it'd be nice if you could edit your answer and add some explanation above.