# Get index of li with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using JQuery I'd like to get the index of the current `li` that I'm on when I click the `button` in the `tabpanel` residing in this list of BootStrap tabs.

```
<ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-pills nav-wizard pill-font" 
  role="tablist" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#start" 
    data-toggle="tab">Before We Start</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#setup" aria-controls="setup" 
    role="tab">Setup</a></li>      
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#signup" aria-controls="Signing Up" 
    role="tab">Signing Up</a></li>      
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#speed" role="tab">Shipping Speeds</a</li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#fulfill" role="tab">Fulfillment</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#product" 
    role="tab">Products</a></li>          
</ul>
```

I'm going to be using a counter in the button within each `tabpanel` so I can go forward and back. This is my JQuery without the counter..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#mytabs li:eq(2) a').tab('show');
  });
});
```

Right now it just has the index `2` but if I can find the index of the current `li` I'll be able to add and subtract from it to get the `li` I want.

I tried with `this` but that just returns the `index` of the button, which isn't what I want.

---

Thanks everyone, a mish mash of everyone's answer turned into this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    var length = $('#mytabs li a').length
    alert(length);
    index=index+1;
    $('#mytabs li:eq('+index+') a').tab('show');
  });
});
```

Comment: Use this.parent()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. (Add the full HTML code please.)

Comment: Shoot, nope. says its undefined

Comment: Perhaps you have the syntax wrong? Try it like this $(this).parent()

Comment: confusing question..please tell in detail

Comment: I see no buttons in the li

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297964/bootstrap-tabs-next-previous-buttons-for-forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        $('#mytabs li:eq(index) a').tab('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: "window" does not have a parent element.

Comment: Who said anything about window? He is clicking a button nested inside of an li. this is the button. And parent is the li

Comment: in this scope, `this` refers to the `window` object.

Comment: How so? The element that is clicked is the button.

Comment: my mistake.. i didn't notice the click handler. still, this is wrong though. the button is not located inside the tabs themselves so `$(this)` is still irrelevant.

Comment: replace `$(this)` with `$("#mytabs").find(".active")` and replace `$('#mytabs li:eq(index) a')` with `$('#mytabs li:eq('+index+') a')` and the answer will be correct and i will remove the downvote.

Comment: also, you should check the length of `$('#mytabs li:eq('+index+') a')` before activating it to make sure there even is a next tab.

Comment: Neh. I'm good. If you reread his question, you will see that he said the button will be inside the tab panel. As others have said, there is some missing information in this question regarding the buttons. Based on the information provided, I made my best guess as to what functionality the OP was looking for. Without more information, you can't say I'm wrong, because you too are just using your best guess as to what the OP wants.

Comment: i'm not guessing. people from all over the world use this site and a lot of them are not native english speakers, so get used to reading bad descriptions. however the op did post their mark-up, and nowhere in the `<ul>` is there a next or previous tab button. so i do know for sure that `$(this)` is irrelevant. shame that you won't fix it because it appears this is what she/he was looking for. I will correct your answer and add it to my own.

Comment: Yea this is just about right.. this will work! Thanks to @user1289451 and Pamblam

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.index` to get de index of the element what you want in an array or list. It will be return the position or -1 (if it fails finding the element/value).

**You can use it like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var index = $('#mytabs li').index($(this));

      if(index > -1){
          $('#mytabs li:eq('+ index +') a').tab('show');
      }
  });
});
```

If you want to use `"this"`, I can show you how:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var element = $(this);
  });
});
```

If you want to add a class to the element you can use `element.addClass("yourClass")` to get it.

I wish it that help to you.

P.D: I recommend change your jQuery selector from `:button` to `#mytabs li`, so you can get the exact element that you has been click, or you can use `element.closest("li")` to get the parent li.

Comment: jQuery element group does not have an `indexOf` method as it is not an array or a string.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't, it was my fault it should be `.index()` or `.find()`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
   $(function() {
      $("li").click(function() {
         var li = $(this);

          console.log( li.parent().find("li").index(li));
      });
   });
```

Returns you the index of the `li` you clicked.